# Creating java program to solve an equation

Tags: java, eclipse

So I'm in an into to Java course and its my second year of college, my professor is unwilling to help me with this.

I was doing well, learning from scratch and using Eclipse, and I get an error which I don't understand because my other lines were fine.

Error is:

```
Syntax error on token "(", Name expected after this token

package project1;

public class BirthRates {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println((365*24*60*60 / 7));
    System.out.println((365*24*60*60 / 13));
    System.out.println((365*24*60*60 / 45));
    System.out.println**((**312,032,486 + 4505142 - 2425846 + 700800));

}
```

}

The error appears with the (( in the asterisk.

My problem that i'm solving is http://faculty.stcc.edu/silvestri/csci111/images/Prob1-11.jpg 
I literally am struggling so hard trying to learn this, its hard not being able to ask the one whos "teaching" you so if anyone could lead me in the right direction i would be forever thankful.

Comment: Take the `,` out of `312,032,486`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers do not take formatting commas in them

try

```
System.out.println(312032486 + 4505142 - 2425846 + 700800);
```

Comment: If separating groups of digits in literal values is useful to you, Java 7+ allows you to use the `_` character for this purpose, so `312_032_486` would be valid.

Comment: Wow the _ worked to fix the problem! Thanks guys, much appreciated.

Comment: I need 15 reputation to upvote, but ill be around for awhile now that i know how amazing this site is. Question, in my coding is there any way to label my lines so my professor will easily know which number belongs to what? Like a way that doesnt affect the code in the line

Example: Children Born(label) System.out.println((365*24*60*60 / 7));

Comment: @DevinWesolowski if an answer solved your problem, you should be able to _accept_ it as the solution to your own question by clicking the checkmark next to the single best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove asterisk and instead of printing first three lines, store each of them in variable. After 1 year,
 `Current population = (Current population + Birth+ Immigrant - Death)` 
print and repeat it five times for five years.

Comment: I finished my entire thing already :) your advice was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ** in the last System.out.println method like and remove , from numbers

```
 System.out.println((312032486 + 4505142 - 2425846 + 700800));
```